# How to properly enque css in to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to en-queue css in WordPress.
Here is my code:

```
function adding_styles()
{
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-css', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
    // Register the style like this for a plugin:
    wp_register_style( 'custom-style', plugins_url( '/css/custom-style.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '20120208', 'all' );

    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the style:
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-css' );
    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the style:
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'adding_styles' );
```

However, jquery-ui.css doesn't load. Can anybody guess the error here??

Comment: could you tell what error it throws in developer tools -> console in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to add path to the CSS file -

> wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-css',get_stylesheet_uri() );

EDIT -

It will clearly works with the URL -

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-css', http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css );
```

Reference  - [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

Look for`$src` parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can add javascript & css in wordpress like this

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_js() {
        wp_enqueue_script('custom_wp_admin_js', plugins_url() . '/dynamic-headers/dynamic-header.js');
    }

    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_js');
```

Add this code in function.php file.

-
Thanks